# std::wcout, why is the printed character not the same as the input?

Tags: c++, string, unicode, unicode-string

While attempting to print "é" with std::wcout the output console instead prints "Ú"

https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl using this website I tried to print "é" using both L"é" or it's character code 0x00E9 but I always endup with the "Ú" character instead, std::cout << "é" also produces the same output

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    // Prints the weird U
    std::wcout << static_cast<wchar_t>(0x00E9);
    // Also prints the weird U
    std::wcout << L"é";
    // Also prints the weird U
    std::cout << "é";
    return 0;
}
```

`

So, can anyone point me to what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Did you change the code page of the console to unicode?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850

Comment: This question is treated as a duplicate but it links to a C question (not C++)..